# I need help with Meraki AP configuration

Tags: cisco, network, meraki

Hello everyone i have this port gi2/0/41 was configured for work station and port gi1/0/18 is configured for Meraki Ap , i need to correct the configuration in port gi2/0/41 and make is as the same port gi1/0/18, i do not want effect the network or cause issue and i'm new in network environment

```
BLDG-B-IDF-01#show run int gi1/0/18
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 119 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
 description MERAKI AP
 switchport trunk native vlan 103
 switchport mode trunk
end

BLDG-B-IDF-01#show run int gi2/0/41
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 617 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/41
 description MERAKI AP
 switchport access vlan 110
 switchport trunk native vlan 103
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
 switchport voice vlan 922
 switchport port-security maximum 5
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security aging time 1
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 switchport port-security
 storm-control broadcast level 2.00 1.00
 auto qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 service-policy input AutoQos-4.0-Trust-Dscp-Input-Policy
 service-policy output AutoQos-4.0-Output-Policy
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make them the same by typing (or pasting) these commands:

```
config t
default interface gi 2/0/41
interface Gi 2/0/41
 description MERAKI AP
 switchport trunk native vlan 103
 switchport mode trunk
end
```

Comment: Yes Sir i did it same thing i just need to know do i need to delete the rest, these are below

Comment: {switchport nonegotiate
 switchport voice vlan 922
 switchport port-security maximum 5
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security aging time 1
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 switchport port-security
 storm-control broadcast level 2.00 1.00
 auto qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 service-policy input AutoQos-4.0-Trust-Dscp-Input-Policy
 service-policy output AutoQos-4.0-Output-Policy
end}

Comment: If you use the `default interface gi 2/0/41` command, it will clear all that out

Comment: what is the default interface gi 2/0/41 command Sir? thanks for your help an support as well